# How to send "multiple retrofit requests" to server with correct sort?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm sending multiple pictures to the server with a while loop.These pictures are inside of a String array(Base64).When the pictures uploaded to server, they didn't sort correctly. For example my first image ranks 5th or my last image ranks 1th. I want to correct ranking. How to solve this ?

```
                            final String[] images = new String[10];

                            i = 0;
                            while (i < mClipData.getItemCount()) {

                                try {
                                    images[i] = imageToString(i);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                Call<SetPersonalInfos> requests = restApiClass.addImage(token, post_id, images[i]);
                                requests.enqueue(new Callback<SetPersonalInfos>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<SetPersonalInfos> call, Response<SetPersonalInfos> response) {

                                        Log.i("images index",i+"");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<SetPersonalInfos> call, Throwable t) {

                                    }
                                });

                                i++;

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: either you can send the pictures serially or you should add some header field which will tell the index to the server